# How do I add the option for Buckets in Salesforce Report Builder

Tags: salesforce, report

How do I add the option for Buckets in Salesforce Report Builder

[image: Salesforce Report Fields without bucket folder]

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the License.  Lightning Sales Cloud- Professional Edition.

No Joined Reports
No Bucket Fields
No Cross Filters (e.g. Accounts without Opportunities)
No Dynamic Dashboards
No Scheduled Dashboards (you can schedule a Report)
50 Custom Report Types vs. 200 in Enterprise Edition